# How to load swf created with flipbook maker into flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to load the swf created by 'flip book maker' into my project.
the files created by flipbook maker are

- book.swf
- framework.swf

I used the following code

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                   
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("book.swf");
myLoader.load(url);                                    
addChild(myLoader);``
```

the framework.swf is linked with book.swf, so it cannot run alone.
When I run the movie it shows the Error #2032, Stream error to framework.swf

book.swf and framework.swf both are in the same directory.They are generated by flip book maker What I needed is to load the book.swf into my project at a particular frame. I need help in AS3 for this purpose.
How to fix it..?
please help me..!

Answer (score 1):

Error #2032 means that your Flash application could not load the framework.swf for some reason (you know this already of course). What you need to find out is why. Possible reasons are: you have the wrong URL, the framework.swf is not in the place you expect, there are crossdomain restrictions on the file you are trying to access ( you did not state where frameworks.swf).

What I would suggest doing is using a web debugging proxy tool like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Firebug (is a Firefox extension) and take a look at the http requests to get more information on your error. You may find out that frameworks.swf is not in the location you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a IOError event triggered by Adobe Flash. Most likely the file just isn't found. Check your path and make sure you place the .swf file in your bin-debug directory if you're doing this from within Adobe Flash Builder